# pass ajax variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I would like to know how can I pass ajax variable to javascript, I an working on this example of code. Notice: append is work but it  is not the best solution

```
$.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             dataType: "json",
             url: "get_promesse_done.php",
             data: {num : num,prmaff : prmaff},
             success: function(data1) {
                        var f= '<td >'+data1[0]+'</td>';
                        var y = '<td >'+data1[1]+'</td>';
                        var x = '<td >'+data1[2]+'</td>';
                        var  tab9='<tr>'+f+y+x+'</tr>';

                                  // $('#testb').append(tab9);
             }
            });

        ss1='<td bgcolor=#27ec04><table id="testb">'+tab9+'</table></td>';
```

Comment: "pass ajax variable to javascript" That does not make any sense. AJAX is just a way of requesting data from a server.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with [JavaScript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/2151050) because `tab9` is undefined the parent scope of `$.ajax`. All variables defined in `success` scope are inaccessible from the global. Another is that `$.ajax` is asynchronous (non-blocking) and allows the execution of code after it, and you assume that `ss1` will have the value of `tab9` from AJAX, but in fact, it does not.

You could define `tab9` in the parent scope of `$.ajax` `success`, and update that. Another thing is to keep your code more readable, is wrapping what you want to happen in a function that would be called after AJAX is completed.

```
// define these in advance.
var ss1,
    tab9;

$.ajax({
    /* settings */
    success: onSuccess // set callback to onSuccess;
});

// this will be called with all arguments of $.ajax.success
function onSuccess(data){

         var f= '<td >'+data1[0]+'</td>';
         var y = '<td >'+data1[1]+'</td>';
         var x = '<td >'+data1[2]+'</td>';
         tab9='<tr>'+f+y+x+'</tr>'; // update tab9

         ss1='<td bgcolor=#27ec04><table id="testb">'+tab9+'</table></td>'; // update ss1

         // append to dom or whatever you want.

}
```